# Borderlands 2 for Mac crashes on launch

Tags: steam, technical-issues, borderlands-2, macos

I recently downloaded Borderlands 2 through steam on my Mac OS X Lion machine, to get this error output:

```
Process: Borderlands2 [16081] Path: /Users/Jamie ProBook/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Borderlands 2/Borderlands2.app/Contents/MacOS/Borderlands2 Identifier: Borderlands2 Version: ??? (???) Code Type: X86 (Native) Parent Process: steam [16054]
Date/Time:       2014-06-28 14:04:27.786 -0700 OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549) Report Version:  6
Interval Since Last Report:          89013 sec Crashes Since Last Report:           3 Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1 Anonymous UUID:                      6D43081E-4D05-44C0-B058-C53DF2A3E0BA
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Crashed Thread:  0  MainThrd  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information: abort() called
Thread 0 Crashed:  MainThrd  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0   libSystem.B.dylib                0x962a3c5a __kill + 10 1   libSystem.B.dylib                0x962a3c4c kill$UNIX2003 + 32 2   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x963365a5 raise + 26 3   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x9634c6e4 abort + 93 4   com.apple.HIServices              0x90dfd310 _RegisterApplication + 6449 5   com.apple.HIServices             0x90dfb9b3 GetCurrentProcess + 50 6 com.apple.HIToolbox             0x90e4fe73 GetSystemUIMode + 47 7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x90e4fe15 IsMenuBarVisible + 41 8   com.apple.AppKit               0x943d3de6 _NSInitializeAppContext + 59 9   com.apple.AppKit                0x943d36a0 -[NSApplication init] + 738 10  com.apple.AppKit                 0x943d31d9 +[NSApplication sharedApplication] + 153 11  com.apple.AppKit                0x9460d0d7 NSApplicationLoad + 101 12  com.aspyr.borderlands2.steam     0x000a50a8 std::_Deque_base<CQuickTimePlayer*, std::allocator<CQuickTimePlayer*>
>::_M_create_nodes(CQuickTimePlayer***, CQuickTimePlayer***) + 404 13  com.aspyr.borderlands2.steam     0x0000248c 0x1000 + 5260 14  com.aspyr.borderlands2.steam   0x0005f50b std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, tagWNDCLASSEXA*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, tagWNDCLASSEXA*> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, tagWNDCLASSEXA*> >
>::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, tagWNDCLASSEXA*> >*) + 1039 15  com.aspyr.borderlands2.steam    0x00002465 0x1000 + 5221

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x96269382 kevent + 10 1   libSystem.B.dylib                0x96269a9c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 215 2 libSystem.B.dylib               0x96268f59 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 163 3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96268cfe _dispatch_worker_thread2
+ 240 4   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x96268781 _pthread_wqthread + 390 5   libSystem.B.dylib                0x962685c6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2: 0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x96268412
__workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x962689a8 _pthread_wqthread + 941 2   libSystem.B.dylib                0x962685c6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):   eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x9634c693  ecx: 0xbfffe2ec  edx: 0x962a3c5a   edi: 0x03410970  esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0xbfffe308  esp: 0xbfffe2ec    ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00000286  eip: 0x962a3c5a   cs: 0x00000007    ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000037   cr2: 0x033da000

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -  0x1e74ffb +com.aspyr.borderlands2.steam 1.8.2 (117917) <6B3D5B1D-BD8D-3455-95D7-43FB98395851> /Users/Jamie ProBook/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common/Borderlands 2/Borderlands2.app/Contents/MacOS/Borderlands2  0x3292000 -  0x32b2ff7
+gameoverlayrenderer.dylib ??? (???) <18026339-0CC6-30AE-AB9A-CE14DA188AB0> /Applications/Steam.app/Contents/MacOS/osx32/gameoverlayrenderer.dylib 0x32d1000 -  0x32d2ff3 +steamloader.dylib ??? (???) <B203BC3A-0BB3-3693-B6EE-1CAD86A1BFDE> /Applications/Steam.app/Contents/MacOS/osx32/steamloader.dylib  0x32d5000 -  0x32daff3 +libsteam_api.dylib ??? (???) <ED4F589C-80F1-3706-9542-D733E527505A> /Users/Jamie ProBook/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common/Borderlands 2/Borderlands2.app/Contents/MacOS/libsteam_api.dylib  0x32df000 -  0x330dfc7 +libBinkMacx86.dylib ??? (???) <E82C2360-C63F-FDD8-4F4F-0B9143BF58ED> /Users/Jamie ProBook/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common/Borderlands 2/Borderlands2.app/Contents/MacOS/libBinkMacx86.dylib  0x3323000 -  0x334bffb +com.aspyr.gameguide 1.0 (712) <D23DDD76-1977-33DD-A12A-03AC4DC00C6F> /Users/Jamie ProBook/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common/Borderlands 2/Borderlands2.app/Contents/Frameworks/AspyrGameGuide.framework/Versions/A/AspyrGameGuide 0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe4162b  dyld 132.1 (???) <749D24EE-54BD-D74B-D305-C13F5E6C95D8> /usr/lib/dyld 0x9000b000 - 0x90012ff3  com.apple.print.framework.Print 6.1 (237.1) <F5AAE53D-5530-9004-A9E3-2C1690C5328E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print 0x904cf000 - 0x90539fe7  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <411D87F4-B7E1-44EB-F201-F8B4F9227213> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib 0x9053a000 - 0x9053eff7  libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???) <09540618-2ED1-72C4-61CB-938B35927568> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib 0x905f2000 - 0x905fbff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <E9C40767-DA6A-6CCB-8B00-2D5706753000> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration 0x905fc000 - 0x90639ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.8 (1.10.2) <50E4D49B-4F61-446F-1C21-1B2BA814713D> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration 0x9063a000 - 0x90768fe7  com.apple.CoreData 102.1 (251) <87FE6861-F2D6-773D-ED45-345272E56463> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData 0x90946000 - 0x909defe7  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.11 (6.5.11) <F36DB665-A88B-7F5B-6244-6A2E7FFFF668> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos 0x909df000 - 0x90a10ff7  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <D18E2E76-DBF4-6930-039A-F66CA0D120B3> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib 0x90a11000 - 0x90a11ff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <51CFA89A-33DB-90ED-26A8-67D461718A4A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices 0x90a76000 - 0x90a92fe3  com.apple.openscripting 1.3.1 (???) <2A748037-D1C0-6D47-2C4A-0562AF799AC9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting 0x90b02000 - 0x90b4ffeb  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.1 (6.1) <136BFA48-D456-B677-3B5D-40A6946C3A09> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer 0x90b82000 - 0x90b82ff7  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <ABF97DA4-3BDF-6FFD-6239-B023CA1F7974> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib 0x90b8e000 - 0x90c10ffb  SecurityFoundation ??? (???) <2E1F1AF0-A258-D215-2600-5DF03896D1F1> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation 0x90c29000 - 0x90c29ff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6) <3891A689-4F38-FACD-38B2-4BF937DE30CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate 0x90c2a000 - 0x90c49ff7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.2 (45.6) <EB53CAA4-5EE2-C356-A954-5775F7DDD493> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo 0x90c4a000 - 0x90c4aff7  liblangid.dylib ??? (???) <B99607FC-5646-32C8-2C16-AFB5EA9097C2> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib 0x90ca2000 - 0x90ddffe7  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <423BDE4D-5082-B6CA-BB2C-E22A037235A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox 0x90df6000 - 0x90df9fe7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility
1.0.0) <1622A54F-1A98-2CBE-B6A4-2122981A500E> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib 0x90dfa000 - 0x90e4dff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.3 (???) <1D3C4587-6318-C339-BD0F-1988F246BE2E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices 0x90e4e000 - 0x91172fef  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.6.5 (???) <21164164-41CE-61DE-C567-32E89755CB34> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox 0x91174000 - 0x91177ff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <37F56237-4ABA-E5B5-968D-70FFE357E8E0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib 0x91178000 - 0x9158eff7  libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <C4FB303A-DB4D-F9E8-181C-129585E59603> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 0x91ae1000 - 0x91bbbfff  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.11 (1.5.11) <800F2040-9211-81A7-B438-7712BF51DEE3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv 0x91ffe000 - 0x91fffff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <93EC71F1-4D4E-F456-8EFE-32E7EFD7A064> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit 0x92000000 - 0x92064ffb  com.apple.htmlrendering 72 (1.1.4) <4D451A35-FAB6-1288-71F6-F24A4B6E2371> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HTMLRendering.framework/Versions/A/HTMLRendering 0x921f6000 - 0x9262bff7  libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <5E2D2283-57DE-9A49-1DB0-CD027FEFA6C2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib 0x9262c000 - 0x9263afe7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <33C1B260-ED05-945D-FC33-EF56EC791E2E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib 0x9263b000 - 0x9263bff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices 38 (38) <8012B504-3D83-BFBB-DA65-065E061CFE03> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices 0x9274d000 - 0x92759ff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <9A441C48-2D18-E716-5F38-CBEAE6A0BB3E> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib 0x927d6000 - 0x9354efe7  com.apple.WebCore 6534.59 (6534.59.6) <5C71C61C-0657-1B0E-397F-4D0A81872C93> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore 0x935a8000 - 0x93654fe7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.12.4 (454.12.4) <DEDCD006-389F-967F-3405-EDF541F406D7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork 0x93655000 - 0x93667ff7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.11 (207.11) <6FF4F2D6-B8CD-AE13-56CB-17437EE5B741> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport 0x9366f000 - 0x936b1ff7  libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <8A4721DE-25C4-C8AA-EA90-9DA7812E3EBA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib 0x93772000 - 0x93776ff7  libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <2251F789-B187-0837-6E38-A0E5C7C4FA3C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib 0x93812000 - 0x93836ff7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <50E17B4D-63D6-24D3-702F-6A6E912A55EA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib 0x94082000 - 0x941fdfe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.6 (550.44) <F88C95CD-1264-782D-A1F5-204739847E93> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation 0x9427b000 - 0x94293ff7  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <F9AFC571-3539-6B46-ABF9-46DA2B608819> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory 0x94294000 - 0x942e4fe7  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???) <AB182CEC-188A-F2BC-21E1-0059FD3B2598> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib 0x94303000 - 0x943a0fe3  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.3 (362.3) <15B47388-16C8-97DA-EEBB-1709E136169E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices 0x943a1000 - 0x943a7fe7  com.apple.CommerceCore 1.0 (9.1) <521D067B-3BDA-D04E-E1FA-CFA526C87EB5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore 0x943d0000 - 0x94cb3ff7  com.apple.AppKit 6.6.8 (1038.36) <A353465E-CFC9-CB75-949D-786F6F7732F6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit 0x94cb4000 - 0x94d70fff  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.8 (4.6.8) <920DD017-8B41-7334-E554-A85DB99EBD5A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync 0x94d71000 - 0x94d77fff  com.apple.CommonPanels 1.2.4 (91) <2438AF5D-067B-B9FD-1248-2C9987F360BA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels 0x952eb000 - 0x952edff7  com.apple.securityhi 4.0 (36638) <C7DA80C1-DCFD-C321-08DA-5E6946CA66E0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI 0x96242000 - 0x963e9ff7  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.11 (compatibility
1.0.0) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib 0x963ea000 - 0x96492ffb  com.apple.QD 3.36 (???) <FA2785A4-BB69-DCB4-3BA3-7C89A82CAB41> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD 0x96493000 - 0x9650dfff  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.6 (3.2.6) <156A532C-0B60-55B0-EE27-D02B82AA6217> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio 0x96569000 - 0x9656cffb  com.apple.help 1.3.2 (41.1) <8AC20B01-4A3B-94BA-D8AF-E39034B97D8C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help 0x9656d000 - 0x965a0ff7  com.apple.AE 496.5 (496.5) <BF9673D5-2419-7120-26A3-83D264C75222> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE 0x965a1000 - 0x965c7ffb  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.2 (1.1.2) <43E1D565-6E01-3681-F2E5-72AE4C3A097A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices 0x96680000 - 0x96684ff7  IOSurface ??? (???) <235E7E3D-B6E5-0AAA-C41A-7AC1F54A7EBF> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface 0x96e45000 - 0x96e50ff7  libGL.dylib ??? (???) <3E34468F-E9A7-8EFB-FF66-5204BD5B4E21> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib 0x9706e000 - 0x97100fe7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.3 (312.7) <7410D1B2-655D-68DA-D4B9-2C65747B6817> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore 0x97101000 - 0x973fbfef  com.apple.QuickTime 7.6.6 (1800) <D3538A45-5F4B-262A-06AB-64C1EBAC4A33> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/Versions/A/QuickTime 0x973fc000 - 0x97459ff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <3DABAB9C-4949-F441-B077-0498F8E47A35> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit 0x97497000
- 0x974b8fe7  com.apple.opencl 12.3.6 (12.3.6) <B4104B80-1CB3-191C-AFD3-697843C6BCFF> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL 0x974b9000 - 0x975c5fe7  libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <6167CEB0-D8D6-C4D9-DD74-49755ADB540F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib 0x975c6000 - 0x9760afe7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.15) <74F05E64-2A68-BA10-CCD4-128D164E5A0F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata 0x9764c000 - 0x976adfe7  com.apple.CoreText 151.13 (???) <23F359DA-D845-5C50-4DF3-19E858CF2B2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText 0x976ae000 - 0x9795bfff  com.apple.JavaScriptCore 6534.59 (6534.59.11) <7F623AA5-A11B-4C26-D2FD-EB5B9DE73F85> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/JavaScriptCore 0x9795c000 - 0x979f7fe7  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 275.19 (???) <2E83B3E9-AF39-36FC-5D05-CC1E952098AB> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS 0x97ad7000 - 0x97b1aff7  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <6CC3CE6A-7024-C685-EADA-7F9DC27128E2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib 0x97b1b000 - 0x97b22ff7  com.apple.agl 3.0.12 (AGL-3.0.12) <61A74CE1-750D-9CAB-B780-306841739EE1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL 0x97b6b000 - 0x97b89fe7  libPng.dylib ??? (???) <6C0B95D7-9634-E044-0B79-F1DD56961C33> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib 0x97da3000 - 0x97da5ff7  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <090420B3-CB65-9F7B-5349-D42F2F9693B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib 0x97da6000 - 0x97e71fef  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 359.2 (359.2) <7C16D9C8-6F41-5754-17F7-2659D9DD9579> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices 0x97e72000 - 0x980e3fef  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.8 (751.63) <69B3441C-B196-F2AD-07F8-D8DD24E4CD8C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation 0x98162000 - 0x981a6ff3  com.apple.coreui 2 (114) <2234855E-3BED-717F-0BFA-D1A289ECDBDA> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI 0x981c0000 - 0x981ceff7  com.apple.opengl 1.6.14 (1.6.14) <82622F67-E032-0BF6-A78D-50B346E8D0FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL 0x98251000 - 0x98351fe7  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <BE7FCD73-03B5-25A4-FCA4-D4980F1488D6> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib 0x98352000 - 0x98352ff7  com.apple.Carbon 150 (152) <734BDB59-8B13-54FA-0653-AA8623DF9846> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon 0x983ac000 - 0x9842cfeb  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0) <9E18AEA5-F4B4-8BE5-EEA9-818FC4F46FD9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit 0x9842d000 - 0x98798ff7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.3 (227.37) <E323A5CC-499E-CA9E-9BC3-537231449CAA> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore 0x98895000 - 0x989befe7  com.apple.WebKit 6534.59 (6534.59.10) <73348DE8-9C7D-3BD9-8E9D-86E5BE67B1D1> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit 0x989bf000 - 0x989d3fe7  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <14CB053A-7C47-96DA-E415-0906BA1B78C9> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib 0x989e8000 - 0x98ac8fe7  com.apple.vImage 4.1 (4.1) <D029C515-08E1-93A6-3705-DD062A3A672C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage 0x98b02000 - 0x98bbafeb  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???) <D2D0C922-5ED1-3AE9-6F99-707C74DF3E62> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib 0x98bdd000 - 0x98c23ff7  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <29422A70-87CF-10E2-CE59-FEE1234CFAAE> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib 0x98c55000 - 0x98c69ffb  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <57DD5458-4F24-DA7D-0927-C3321A65D743> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis 0x98cbb000 - 0x98f21ff7  com.apple.security 6.1.2 (55002) <E88E133F-5FB3-446F-B753-2B8AD577B46A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security 0x98f22000 - 0x98f4aff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <E761F29A-328B-29D9-3DF0-023F2C21E500> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib 0x98f4b000 - 0x98f6dfef  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.16) <5566E769-6459-78A7-DD2C-1D3068BD3932> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService 0x98fe6000 - 0x98fe6ff7  com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <FF4DC8B6-0AB0-DEE8-ADA8-7B57645A1F36> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib 0x990dc000 - 0x990e6fe7  com.apple.audio.SoundManager 3.9.3 (3.9.3) <5F494955-7290-2D91-DA94-44B590191771> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonSound.framework/Versions/A/CarbonSound 0x990e7000 - 0x991a0fe7  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <52438E77-55D1-C231-1936-76F1369518E4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib 0x991e2000 - 0x9921cff7  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <A6C207E3-7B42-926D-9C93-BE3F50B92496> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib 0x99278000 - 0x99326ff3  com.apple.ink.framework 1.3.3 (107) <233A981E-A2F9-56FB-8BDE-C2DEC3F20784> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink 0x9942a000 - 0x9943aff7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <C8744EA3-0AB7-CD03-E639-C4F2B910BE5D> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib 0x9943e000 - 0x9975eff3  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.39 (861.39) <5C59805C-AF39-9010-B8B5-D673C9C38538> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore 0x9975f000 - 0x997a2ff7  com.apple.NavigationServices 3.5.4 (182) <8DC6FD4A-6C74-9C23-A4C3-715B44A8D28C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/NavigationServices.framework/Versions/A/NavigationServices 0x9988e000 - 0x998fdff7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <595A5539-9F54-63E6-7AAC-C04E1574B050> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib 0x99928000 - 0x9993dfff  com.apple.ImageCapture 6.1 (6.1) <B909459A-EAC9-A7C8-F2A9-CD757CDB59E8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture 0x999ef000 - 0x999efff7  com.apple.Cocoa 6.6 (???) <EA27B428-5904-B00B-397A-185588698BCC> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa 0x99a27000
- 0x99a31ffb  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1) <7486003F-8FDB-BD6C-CB34-DE45315BD82C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition 0x99a32000 - 0x99a43ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6) <3036AD83-4F1D-1028-54EE-54165E562650> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis 0x99a44000 - 0x99a94ff7  com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0.2 (2020) <C96C8A99-A40C-8B9C-1FBA-A0F46AC92F17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls 0x99adb000 - 0x99ae8ff7  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.2 (3.2.2) <DDC9C397-C35F-8D7A-BB24-3D1B42FA5FAB> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS 0x99ae9000
- 0x99b09fe7  libresolv.9.dylib 41.1.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <8C2B5FA8-2469-21C7-D297-F95A0FFE5F19> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib 0x99b0a000 - 0x99ccdfeb  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.6 (3.0.6) <AE641FAD-DF38-AE31-B45B-85AEE7AF3A45> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO 0x99cce000 - 0x99ccfff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1) <2D970A9B-77E8-EDC0-BEC6-7580D78B2843> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent 0x99ce0000 - 0x9a4cf557  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.545.0 (???) <1D9DC7A5-228B-42CB-7018-66F42C3A9BB3> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics 0x9a509000 - 0x9a60bfe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility
0.9.8) <EB34F049-D9E1-BF19-CF03-B26A0352D40C> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0x9a7be000 - 0x9a7c3ff7  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <C1B46982-7D3B-3CC4-3BC2-3E4B595F0231> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory 0x9a9fe000 - 0x9ab80fe7  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility
1.0.0) <60FF302E-5FAE-749B-BC70-0496DC2FBF2D> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib 0x9ac16000 - 0x9acc3fe7  libobjc.A.dylib
227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9F8413A6-736D-37D9-8EB3-7986D4699957> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Model: iMac11,2, BootROM IM112.0057.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core i3,
3.06 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.64f5 Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 4670, ATI Radeon HD 4670, PCIe, 256 MB Memory Module: global_name AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x8F), Atheros 9280: 2.1.14.6 Bluetooth: Version 2.4.5f3, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1 Serial ATA Device: SAMSUNG HD502HJ, 465.76 GB Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5680H USB Device: Hub, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 2 USB Device: USB Flash Drive, 0x05dc  (Lexar Media, Inc.), 0xa81d, 0xfa140000 / 5 USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4 USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8215, 0xfa111000 / 6 USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8403, 0xfa120000 / 3 USB Device: Hub, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2 USB Device: Composite Device, 0x04b3  (IBM Corporation), 0x310d, 0xfd130000 / 5 USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 4 USB Device: Built-in iSight, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8502, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Does anybody know what's wrong and how I can get it to properly launch?

Answer (score 2):

Please exit Steam and remove the Steam application from the location you installed it in (Applications by default) by dragging it to the Trash.

Also go to the folder Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Steam

Note: If you are using Lion please do the following to access your Steam folder:

1. Click "Go" in the menu bar
2. Click "Go to Folder..."
3. Type "~/Library/Application Support/Steam"
4. Click "Go"

This will take you directly to the folder.

Delete all of the files and folders in the /Steam folder except for /SteamApps.

Then, redownload Steam from http://cdn.store.steampowered.com/pu...ller/steam.dmg and reinstall the application.

Then, you will need to launch Steam.app from your Dock or Applications folder.

With Steam running, re-test the original issue.

Found this, apparently fixes the problem

[Credit](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2900563)

Comment: Tried your method and this returned upon launch of B2: http://pastebin.com/w9z6PRGF

Answer (score 1):

I bought and installed Borderlands 2 for OS X yesterday, and today I saw the same crash log. I found some other threads that suggested upgrading to OS 10.9 Mavericks as a solution, but I'm already on 10.9. I was connected to a TV via a mini Displayport to VGA adapter. I noticed that as soon as I unplugged the external display Borderlands 2 stopped crashing. It seems like there are multiple causes for this error, and having an external monitor connected is one of them. Hope this helps =)